# Can't load contextConfigLocation class on ServletContextHandler from a Service Class

Tags: java, spring, rest, jetty, cxf

I have a project with Spring and several services. I'm trying to include a bunch of rest services in it. The thing is the embedded jetty server is within a @Service instance and for many reasons I can't touch it. So, I've tried to configure that server with my new requirements and I can't.

I've tried for discard with the classic approach outside the project logic, and it works:

```
public class Starter {
public static void main( final String[] args ) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server( 8888 );

    // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
    final ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder( new CXFServlet() );
    final ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();      
    context.setContextPath( "/" );
    context.addServlet( servletHolder, "/rest/*" );     
    context.addEventListener( new ContextLoaderListener() );

    context.setInitParameter( "contextClass", AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class.getName() );
    context.setInitParameter( "contextConfigLocation", AppConfig.class.getName() );

    server.setHandler( context );
    server.start();
    server.join();  
}
```

}

But, if I try to make the same thing within a spring context Service it doesn't work.

If I use the same initialization inside it, I get:

```
WARN  Can't find the the request for http://localhost:8888/rest/api/people's Observer
```

I've tried to modify  in applicationContext.xml to include rest needed classes but in that case the /api/ resource was registered twice.

I'm sure I'm not understanding something :)

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
@Bean 
@DependsOn( "cxf" )
public Server jaxRsServer() {
    JAXRSServerFactoryBean factory = RuntimeDelegate.getInstance().createEndpoint( jaxRsApiApplication(), JAXRSServerFactoryBean.class );
    factory.setBus(cxf()); // <-- THIS!
    factory.setServiceBeans( Arrays.< Object >asList( peopleRestService() ) );
    factory.setProviders( Arrays.< Object >asList( jsonProvider() ) );
    return factory.create();
}
```